# Smooth sliding mat-slider that snaps to ticks

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to get the angular mat-slider to smoothly slide, but when released snaps to the nearest tick.

I have a semi-working demo here: https://github.com/Jeff-Stapleton/Snapping-Mat-Slider

I define my slider like so:

```
<mat-slider
    class="example-margin"
    [disabled]="disabled"
    [invert]="invert"
    [max]="2"
    [min]="0"
    [step]="0.02"
    [tick-interval]="50"
    [(ngModel)]="value">
</mat-slider>
```

I do a 2-way data binding on the `value` I try to intercept the setting and getting of the value to ensure that the value is always rounded to the nearest tick:

```
get value(): number {
  return Math.round(this._value);
}

set value(v) {
  if (this.task !== undefined) {
    this.task.unsubscribe();
  }
  this.task = Observable.interval(500).subscribe(() => {
    v = Math.round(Number(v));
    this._value = v;
  });
}
```

I even went as far as setting up and interval to ensure my changes always took effect. However, even now, it only works about 90% of the time. The slider will stay where it's at when released instead of snapping to the nearest tick. When I inspect the `value` in the developer tools it is correctly rounded to the nearest tick but the slider isn't reflecting the ngModels current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you're over-complicating matters. This is a lot simpler:

```
_value = 0;
get value() {
    return this._value;
}
set value(v) {
    this._value = v;
    const roundedValue = Math.round(this._value);
    if (roundedValue !== this._value) {
        setTimeout((me, newValue) => {
            me._value = newValue;
        }, 0, this, roundedValue);
    }
}
```

You don't need to use the getters and setters for step and tickInterval, or the Observable and Subscription, just update the value property to the rounded value in a timeout.